# Вывести в консоль с помощью цикла квадрат 5x5, используя символ #

Tags: swift

Необходимо вывести с помощью цикла квадрат, понимаю, что это необходимо сделать с помощью вложенных циклах, но не понимаю, как необходимо написать это на языке Swift.
Как я представляю себе это:

```
for i in 1...5 {
print ("#")
for j in 1...5 {
    print("#")
  }
}
```

Но он просто печатает их в строку, не замечая переменные i и j
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это реализовывается?

Answer (score 1):

Добавляете переменную для ряда, во внутреннем цикле набираете ряд, во внешнем выводите

```
var row = ""

for _ in 0..<5 {
  row = ""

  for _ in 0..<5 {
    row += "#"
  }

  print(row)
}
```